# Costliest beer commercial to date?

Tags: specialty-beers, price

What has been the costliest beer commercial to date, who owns it and what are the reasons for it to be so costly?

Adding reliable references would be appreciated .

Answer (score 2):

Going to go with Guinness- $16 million in 2007. Several websites state that  Guinness spent $60 million dollars on there 80th anniversary (birthday) in 2007.

> Moving back to beer and safer ground, Guinness celebrated their 80th birthday in style with an estimated $16 million spend on a TV advert.
>
> That figure is slightly surprising when you appreciate that this advert doesn’t contain any celebrity endorsers. What it does include, however, is a rather precarious domino system of items through an Argentinean village leading up to a pint of Guinness made up of books.
>
> It hurts just trying to work out how many takes it would have required. - [Four of TV’s Most Expensive Adverts](http://livingroom-uk.com/four-tvs-expensive-adverts)

[The 10 Most Expensive TV Commercials Ever Made](http://www.therichest.com/rich-list/the-biggest/the-10-most-expensive-tv-commercials-ever-made/) has this to say about the TV advertisement:

> When celebrating your birthday, you are allowed to be a little extravagant, right? Well, Guinness took its 80th birthday celebration to a whole new level; by spending $16 million on a commercial. With the slogan “Good things happen to those who wait,” the commercial that was shot in Argentina shows a whole village waiting for the revelation of Guinness beer after thousands of objects together with dominoes have to knock each other down one by one. Some of the objects in the sequence include cars, tires, padlocks, suitcases, crutches, chairs, and almost anything that can be found in a village. The commercial does not feature any celebrities, but the concept, the setup, and the use of all the resources is what must have pushed up the cost to $16 million.

The Guinness commercial can be seen here on YouTube: [Guinness Dominos Commercial - Tipping Point.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAQiuutkxdU)

Comment: Ken Graham, again you are astounding, I just love reading your answers.

Comment: @dougal3.0.0 Thanks for the comment!